# I refactored working code into a function - now I can't figure out how to pass the "x" axis column argument

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, refactoring

I'm refactoring some code I wrote to make some elements reusable. I had this code block that would create two plots and combine them and it worked great as a block of code inside the main function.

### My old (working) code

```
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  df_par <- data.frame(samples = bo_par$t)
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = df_par,
    x = samples,
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )
  
  # Create a qq-plot for the resamples
  plot_qq <- gg_qq(
    data = df_par,
    sample = samples,
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    theme = light_mode()
  ) +
    geom_qq_line(color = "blue")
  
  # Combine the plots
  plot_combo <- ggarrange(plot_hist, plot_qq,
                          ncol = 2,
                          nrow = 1,
                          widths = c(600, 600),
                          heights = 300)
```

### Attempt to Refactor

I stripped the code block out and attempted to make it a function.

```
# Function for creating combo plot histogram + q-q
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, xcol, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = data[[xcol]],
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
  
  # Create a qq-plot for the resamples
  plot_qq <- gg_qq(
    data = data,
    sample = data[[xcol]],
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    theme = theme
  ) +
    geom_qq_line(color = "blue")
  
  # Combine the plots
  plot_combo <- ggarrange(plot_hist, plot_qq,
                          ncol = 2,
                          nrow = 1,
                          widths = c(600, 600),
                          heights = 300)
  
  return(plot_combo)
}
```

### The Problem

I can't seem to find a way to appropriately pass the column I want to use for `x` or `sample` in the respective `ggblanket` function calls.  None of these calls work. I get an error about the x aesthetic being discrete instead of continuous or about not being able to mutate something.

```
  plot_combo <- fun_comboPlot(
    data = df_par,
    xcol= "samples",
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )


  plot_combo <- fun_comboPlot(
    data = df_par,
    xcol= df_par$samples,
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )


  plot_combo <- fun_comboPlot(
    data = df_par,
    xcol= samples,
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )
```

### EDIT

To add, this modification to the function also doesn't work (I found something like this in another S.O. question and thought I'd give it a whirl):

```
# Function for creating combo plot histogram + q-q
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, colname, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Store the X-axis column
  xx <- names(data[colname])
  
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = xx,
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
 ...
  
  return(plot_combo)
}
```

Nor does this:

```
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, xcol, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = noquote(xcol),
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
 ...
  
  return(plot_combo)
}
```

Nor does this...

```
library(rlang)

# Function for creating combo plot histogram + q-q
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, xcol, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Unquote xcol using rlang
  xcol_unquoted <- enquo(xcol)
  
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = !!xcol_unquoted,
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
  ...
  return(plot_combo)
}
```

### Whole enchilada

Here's the whole script if anyone wants to try to reproduce:

```
library(boot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggblanket)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)

# Function for creating combo plot histogram + q-q
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, colname, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = data[[colname]],
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
  
  # Create a qq-plot for the resamples
  plot_qq <- gg_qq(
    data = data,
    sample = data[[colname]],
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    theme = theme
  ) +
    geom_qq_line(color = "blue")
  
  # Combine the plots
  plot_combo <- ggarrange(plot_hist, plot_qq,
                          ncol = 2,
                          nrow = 1,
                          widths = c(600, 600),
                          heights = 300)
  
  return(plot_combo)
}


# Define internal functions for bootstrapping
fun_mean <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i]
  return(mean(d, na.rm = TRUE))
}

fun_sd <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i]
  return(sd(d, na.rm = TRUE))
}

fun_2samD <- function(data, i1, i2){
  d1 <- data[i1]
  d2 <- data[i2]
  return(mean(d1 - d2, na.rm = TRUE))
}

bootstrap_2SampDif <- function(bs_data, Res){
    B1 <- boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_2samD, R = Res)
    B2 <- boot(data = bs_data[, 2], statistic = fun_2samD, R = Res)
    Dif <- B1$t - B2$t
    #TODO:  95% CI for dif?
}

bootstrap_est <- function(bs_data, param_type, Res) {
  # Replace all zero values with NA
  bs_data[bs_data == 0] <- NA

  # Choose the bootstrapping function based on param_type
  bo_par <- switch(
      param_type,
      mean = boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_mean, R = Res),
      sd = boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_sd, R = Res),
      stop("Invalid param_type")
    )
  
  # Obtain confidence intervals for the parameter estimate
  ci_par <- boot.ci(bo_par, conf = 0.95, type = "bca")
  
  # Store the confidence interval bounds
  Lci_par <- ci_par$bca[4]
  Uci_par <- ci_par$bca[5]
  
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  df_par <- data.frame(samples = bo_par$t)
  
  plot_combo <- fun_comboPlot(
    data = df_par,
    colname = "samples",
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )
  
  # Store the results
  results_param <- data.frame(
    `Resamples` = Res,
    `Parameter` = paste0(format(bo_par$t0, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         " (",
                         format(Lci_par, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         ",",
                         format(Uci_par, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         ")"
                         )
    )
  
  #Return the plot and results
  return(list("plot" = plot_combo, "results" = results_param))
}

#--------------------------
#Estimate mean and SD for multiple groups
#--------------------------
# populate the data for analysis
mydata <- data.frame(
  Device1 = c(6.3, 8.3, 6.6, 0, 8.4, 8.6),
  Device2 = c(8.2, 8.7, 8.6, 7.9, 7.1, 7.6),
  Device3 = c(7.1, 6.4, 6.6, 8, 7.5, 10.3),
  Device4 = c(8, 7.7, 7.3, 0, 9.4, 6.4),
  Device5 = c(8.5, 6.8, 0, 0, 7.3, 9.7),
  Device6 = c(5.9, 7.5, 6.5, 0, 9.8, 7.8),
  Device7 = c(7.6, 5.3, 6.7, 0, 6.6, 7.4),
  Device8 = c(9.5, 5.6, 8.8, 0, 8.6, 8.3),
  Device9 = c(8.5, 7.4, 0, 0, 9.2, 8.6),
  Device10 = c(7.8, 6.9, 8.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.1)
)

# Initialize empty lists to store the bootstrap function returns
bs_return <- list()
results_group <- list()
plots_group <- list()

# Store column names to use as group ID
column_names <- colnames(mydata)

# Initialize an empty vector to store the IDs
id_vector <- character()

# Create a PDF file to output results/plots
pdf("Bootstrap Results.pdf")

# Estimate the bootstrap parameter and export the results
for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)) {
  # Print status to console
  cat(paste("Group", i, "\n"))
  bs_return <- bootstrap_est(as.data.frame(mydata[, i]), "mean", 500)
  results_group[[i]] <- bs_return$results
  id_vector <- c(id_vector, rep(column_names[i], nrow(bs_return$results)))
  plots_group[[i]] <- bs_return$plot
}

# Add the ID column to the results
results_df <- cbind(ID = id_vector, do.call(rbind, results_group))

# Print the combined table to a text file
write.table(results_df, "Bootstrap Results.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")

# Combine the plots using grid.arrange
combined_plots <- do.call(grid.arrange, plots_group)

# Print the combined table to the PDF file
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(combined_plots)

# Close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is to use "sample" inside the function via `!!sym(colname)`, e.g.

```r
library(boot)
#install.packages("ggblanket")
library(ggblanket)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int, flatten_lgl,
#>     flatten_raw, invoke, splice
library(ggpubr)

# Function for creating combo plot histogram + q-q
fun_comboPlot <- function(data, colname, title, subtitle, theme){
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  plot_hist <- gg_histogram(
    data = data,
    x = !!sym(colname),
    title = title,
    subtitle = subtitle,
    theme = theme
  )
  
  # Create a qq-plot for the resamples
  plot_qq <- gg_qq(
    data = data,
    sample = !!sym(colname),
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    theme = theme
  ) +
    geom_qq_line(color = "blue")
  
  # Combine the plots
  plot_combo <- ggarrange(plot_hist, plot_qq,
                          ncol = 2,
                          nrow = 1,
                          widths = c(600, 600),
                          heights = 300)
  
  return(plot_combo)
}

# Define internal functions for bootstrapping
fun_mean <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i]
  return(mean(d, na.rm = TRUE))
}

fun_sd <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i]
  return(sd(d, na.rm = TRUE))
}

fun_2samD <- function(data, i1, i2){
  d1 <- data[i1]
  d2 <- data[i2]
  return(mean(d1 - d2, na.rm = TRUE))
}

bootstrap_2SampDif <- function(bs_data, Res){
  B1 <- boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_2samD, R = Res)
  B2 <- boot(data = bs_data[, 2], statistic = fun_2samD, R = Res)
  Dif <- B1$t - B2$t
  #TODO:  95% CI for dif?
}

bootstrap_est <- function(bs_data, param_type, Res) {
  # Replace all zero values with NA
  bs_data[bs_data == 0] <- NA
  
  # Choose the bootstrapping function based on param_type
  bo_par <- switch(
    param_type,
    mean = boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_mean, R = Res),
    sd = boot(data = bs_data[, 1], statistic = fun_sd, R = Res),
    stop("Invalid param_type")
  )
  
  # Obtain confidence intervals for the parameter estimate
  ci_par <- boot.ci(bo_par, conf = 0.95, type = "bca")
  
  # Store the confidence interval bounds
  Lci_par <- ci_par$bca[4]
  Uci_par <- ci_par$bca[5]
  
  # Create a histogram for the resamples
  df_par <- data.frame(samples = bo_par$t)
  
  plot_combo <- fun_comboPlot(
    data = df_par,
    colname = "samples",
    title = paste("Group", colnames(bs_data)),
    subtitle = paste("Bootstrap parameter estimate for:", param_type),
    theme = light_mode()
  )
  
  # Store the results
  results_param <- data.frame(
    `Resamples` = Res,
    `Parameter` = paste0(format(bo_par$t0, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         " (",
                         format(Lci_par, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         ",",
                         format(Uci_par, digits = 4, nsmall = 4),
                         ")"
    )
  )
  
  #Return the plot and results
  return(list("plot" = plot_combo, "results" = results_param))
}
```

```r
#Estimate mean and SD for multiple groups
```

```r
# populate the data for analysis
mydata <- data.frame(
  Device1 = c(6.3, 8.3, 6.6, 0, 8.4, 8.6),
  Device2 = c(8.2, 8.7, 8.6, 7.9, 7.1, 7.6),
  Device3 = c(7.1, 6.4, 6.6, 8, 7.5, 10.3),
  Device4 = c(8, 7.7, 7.3, 0, 9.4, 6.4),
  Device5 = c(8.5, 6.8, 0, 0, 7.3, 9.7),
  Device6 = c(5.9, 7.5, 6.5, 0, 9.8, 7.8),
  Device7 = c(7.6, 5.3, 6.7, 0, 6.6, 7.4),
  Device8 = c(9.5, 5.6, 8.8, 0, 8.6, 8.3),
  Device9 = c(8.5, 7.4, 0, 0, 9.2, 8.6),
  Device10 = c(7.8, 6.9, 8.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.1)
)

# Initialize empty lists to store the bootstrap function returns
bs_return <- list()
results_group <- list()
plots_group <- list()

# Store column names to use as group ID
column_names <- colnames(mydata)

# Initialize an empty vector to store the IDs
id_vector <- character()

# Create a PDF file to output results/plots
pdf("Bootstrap Results.pdf", width = 20, height = 15)

# Estimate the bootstrap parameter and export the results
for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)) {
  # Print status to console
  cat(paste("Group", i, "\n"))
  bs_return <- bootstrap_est(as.data.frame(mydata[i]), "mean", 500)
  results_group[[i]] <- bs_return$results
  id_vector <- c(id_vector, rep(column_names[i], nrow(bs_return$results)))
  plots_group[[i]] <- bs_return$plot
}
#> Group 1
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 2
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 3
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 4
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 5
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 6
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 7
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 8
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Group 9
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_bin()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq_line()`).
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_bin()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq_line()`).
#> Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq_line()`).
#> Group 10
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

# Add the ID column to the results
results_df <- cbind(ID = id_vector, do.call(rbind, results_group))

# Print the combined table to a text file
write.table(results_df, "Bootstrap Results.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")

# Combine the plots using grid.arrange
combined_plots <- do.call(grid.arrange, plots_group)

# Print the combined table to the PDF file
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(combined_plots)

# Close the PDF device
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Resulting in: [image: screenshot.png]

---

I also changed "title" (it was printing "mydata[, i]" instead of "Device1" etc) and altered the dimensions of the pdf. For further information about `!!sym()`, see Advanced R Chapter [19](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html?q=quasiquot#quasiquotation) and [20](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html)

Comment: That did it. Thank you!  After a bit of reading, I figured it was some sort of issue with unescaping the quoted characters - I just wasn't able to get it quite right.  Thanks also for the bonus code fixes. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @CBRF23 :)